# Importing XML To A Table From A RESTful Web API

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

Afternoon,

I am trying to import XML data to MS Access using VBA to create a table.  I got the code from a developer that I follow on YouTube and his name is Steven Bishop.  Not trying to take credit for his work and here is a link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8TXif1j82Q

So that said, I am new to XML.  I have to get employee names and their org codes via a XML request and that part of the code works.  Where my code is failing is when I try to save the DOMDocument, I am getting a run time error that says permission is denied.  I talked to one of our admins so I know that my permissions are correct.  I even tried to use a thumb drive to save my XML file to then make the table from there.

```
    Dim reader As New XMLHTTP60

    Dim doc As DOMDocument60


    reader.Open "GET", "URL Goes here", False
    reader.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
    reader.send

    Do Until reader.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If reader.status = 200 Then
        Set doc = reader.responseXML
        doc.Save "C:\XMLTest"

        Application.ImportXML "C:\Desktop\XML Test\tblTest.xml", acStructureAndData

    Else

        MsgBox "Unable to Import Data"

    End If

End Sub

Any ideas on why I am getting this error?
```

Comment: You are not allowed to write to drive c: ! That is a usuall setting. As you want to import from`C:\Desktop\XML Test\tblTest.xml`you should store the file there (with same filename)!

Comment: I tried saving this to a thumb drive and got the same results.

Comment: Use`Currentproject.Path & "\test.xml"`as you should be able to write where your db resides!

Comment: You could also try outputting the string value of the xml doc to the console, just to make sure that the doc object has been instantiated correctly. And then if all's well with that, you could use fileSystemObject to write that text to a file on your filesystem. Assuming you do have the write permissions, I can't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your saving row using file extension like:

```
doc.Save "C:\XMLTest.txt"
```